# $I-cP$ Invertible Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Question:** Assume P is a nonzero $n$ x $n$ matrix, $n \ge 2$, such that $P^2=P$. Let $c\in\mathbb R, c\ne1$. Show that the matrix $I-cP$ is invertible and find its inverse.

I'm having trouble going about this question. By manipulating $Av=\lambda v$, I get that P has eigenvalues $0$ and $1$. I know that if the determinant of $I-cP$ is nonzero then it is invertible, and that if it has a trival kernel it is invertible. But I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As you say, the eigenvalues are limited to $\{0,1\}$, so $\det(\lambda I-P)\neq 0$ for all $\lambda\notin\{0,1\}$. In particular, taking $\lambda:=\frac{1}{c}\notin\{0,1\}$ (we may assume $c\neq 0$, otherwise $I-cP=I$ is clearly invertible) we have $$\det(I-cP)=\det\left(c\left(\frac{1}{c}I-P\right)\right)=c^n\det\left(\frac{1}{c}I-P\right)\neq 0$$ so $I-cP$ is invertible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guide:

\begin{align}(I-cP)(I+dP)&=I-cP+dP-cdP^2 \\
&=I+(-c+d-cd)P\end{align}

We just have to solve for $d$ in

$$-c+d-cd=0$$

I will leave this task to you.

Comment: Hi, what's the intuition behind $d$?

Comment: hmm, I don't really have an intuition for the interpretation of $d$ yet.

Comment: Since $P^2=P$, any polynomial in $P$ is at most degree one. Since $A:=I-cP$ is a polynomial in $P$, one would expect its inverse to also be a polynomial in $P$, and thus (at most) a degree one polynomial in $P$ by the previous sentence. That's my intuition for $d$, but maybe there is a different/better intuition.

Comment: If the question is why did I multiply by $I+dP$, I want to construct $I$ and $P^2$, there is no point considering higher order as by $P^2=P$, we can reduce every polynomial of higher order to linear.

Comment: Actually we can view it as Binomial expansion of $(1-cP)^{-1}$ assuming that it exists.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Find a polynomial for which $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = \frac{1}{1-c}$. We have $f(P) = (I - cP)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $c = 0$ then $I-cP$ is clearly invertible. So assume $c \neq 0$.

If $I-cP$  is not invertible, then there is a vector $x \neq 0$ with $(I-cP)x =0$, that is, $x = cPx$. This implies $Px \neq 0$. Multiplying both sides by $P$ we have $Px = cPx$, i.e., $(1-c)Px = 0$, since $Px \neq 0$ we must have $1-c=0$, i.e., $c=1$. A contradiction.